# Sails.js expire session at given time or every end of day

Tags: node.js, redis, sails.js

**TLDR** version: I wanted the session in sails to expire at a specific given time or date or end of day.

---

I gave up trying to figure out how to expire a session in sails/node at a given time.

the `cookie.maxAge` option in the `sessions.js` seems to be updating the TTL of the session of the key in redis on a given millisecond. So I tried setting each `maxAge` by running

```
req.session.cookie.maxAge = Utility.getEndOfDayMilliseconds();
req.session.save();
```

I created a utility that gets the value of the milliseconds from the current time to end of day.

It works when I am idle in one screen, but when I navigate on pages, the TTL on a session key in redis gets refreshed every pag navigation and the `maxAge` gets back to the `originalMaxAge`. I don't wan't that to happen.

How does one do this? The cookie that is set in my browser is correct but I can change the expire value at a future date so that my session does not expire and keep on refresh a page so that the TTL will refresh.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you may find an answer in the official Sails website documentation > concepts > sessions.